# PHP website on Windows Azure not showing IE 11 mode

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, azure, internet-explorer-11

I am hosting a PHP Wordpress website on my Windows Azure account. However when I run my website in IE11 it has a lot of flaws compared to chrome and firefox, which run perfectly.

However if I press f12 and set my document mode to `edge` it works fine, by default however it is set to `8`. So I was wondering how I can set up my Azure hosting to make my website run in IE11 mode instead of 8.

Any ideas?

It's a bit tricky because of the windows azure hosting, so I can't just modify everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems nobody answered my question, after a few days I figured out it was a really really easy fix, I just added this line to the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```